# Mongodb, time difference between two checkpoints

Tags: mongodb

I m actually developping an application using a Mongodb database.
Actually, there's a system with "checkpoints", a user scan an NFC tag when he enters in a place, and scan this same tag to leave this place.

So, in my database, I have something like :

```
{
   "enterDate":"the-date-iso-string-formatted",
   "leaveDate":"the-date-iso-string-formatted"
}
```

Actually, I need to detect what is the time between two different end point. I mean, how much time the user takes to travel from one place, to the next one.

In fact it corresponds to the avg of all the

> endPoint[1].enterDate- endPoint[0].leaveDate

What is the best way, or the quickest way to manage this ?

Thanks for advance

Comment: Looks like you could use [**aggregation framework**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) for this, in particular you would need to use [**Date**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#date-operators) and [**arithmetic**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#arithmetic-operators) operators to get the desired output. Could you be a more elaborate to provide us with some sample test documents and the expected output so that we can replicate the same behaviour and provide a suitable solution?